# Surefire forkCount not resulting in this number of processes

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I can set the value of the parameter `forkCount` to any desired number, say 12, and I'd expect to have 12 new Java processes of type `surefirebooter` when running tests like these.  But `ps` shows that I only *sometimes* get the 12 expected Java processes (to be precise: I get them extremely rarely).  Instead I typically get less, sometimes even only three or four.  Execution of my hundreds of unit tests also appears to be slow then.

The running processes also often disappear from the `ps` output (terminate, I assume) before the unit tests are done.  In some cases *all* of them, then the execution hangs indefinitely.

Documentation wasn't too clear about this, but I'd expect to have the given number of processes all the time until all unit tests are done.

Maybe the `surefirebooter` processes run into some problem and terminate prematurely.  I see no error message, though.  Where should I see them?  Can I switch on some debug logging?  Switching on the debug mode of Surefire changed the test results, so I didn't follow that path very far.

I'm running ~1600 unit tests in ~400 classes which takes ~7 minutes in the best case.  Execution time varies greatly, sometimes the whole thing terminates after more than an hour.

In some cases, on the other hand, the `surefirebooter` processes continue to run after execution finished (successfully) and puts massive load on the system (so it seems to be busy waiting for something).

Questions:

- Can anybody explain these observed phenomena?
- Can anybody give advice what to change in order to have a more proper execution?  (I. e. with the desired number of `surefirebooter` processes at all times.)
- Can anybody give advice on how to debug the situation?  See messages about what happens with the `surefirebooter` processes?  (I tried using `strace` but that also changed the behavior so dramatically that the call didn't terminate anymore.)

Comment: What version of the Surefire Plugin are you using? `forkCount` is a maximum value, so it may be normal to have less sometimes (not sure), but the execution definitely shouldn't hang. Try to set `<reuseForks>true</reuseForks>`, that will make sure forks are created only once and reused throughout the test. What value are you using for [`parallel`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#parallel)?

Comment: Surefire-version: `2.18.1`.  `reuseForks`: documented as being `true` on default.  I will try out if I experience different results with it being *explicitly* set to `true` and report on the results here.  `parallel` is not used; our classes under test are not designed to work correctly when their unit tests are run in parallel on their instances.  Tests enabling this feature also showed the expected (failing) behavior.

Comment: Explicitly setting `reuseForks` to its documented default `true` doesn't seem to have any influence from my trials.

Answer (score 1):

My hypothesis #1 would be that `oom_killer` can be the culprit. #2 would be that forked processes go into swap and/or spend crazy amount of time garbage collecting stuff

To debug:

1. Which platform you run this on?
2. If that's something of *nix kind, could you please check `dmesg` or `/var/log/messages` for the messages telling about killed processes after the run?
3. In cases where you have processes busy waiting, could you please try a) collect stacktrace with `jstack` (both for forked processes and the main one) b) quantify `massive load on the system` in terms of cpu / memory usage / amount of stuff paged in / paged out
4. If none of those proves useful, I'd try to fork [surefire ForkStarter](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/e0ce6cb021d42d021704f77a689e3b663aebf084/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/booterclient/ForkStarter.java) adding more logging events and comparing the logs of successful runs and failed ones for more clues. (`--debug` or `-X` argument to maven to output debug messages).

Comment: ① I run this in a docker container which is on a Linux box. ② `dmesg` shows nothing, `/var/log/messages` does not exist, `/var/log/syslog` also shows nothing related. ③ ⓐ going to try to when it re-happens. ⓑ On this 64-CPU machine (!) a system load of ~25 appears and piles up to a multiple of it when several are left-over (a load of >400 could be observed once).  I'm neither sure about the memory consumption nor about the actual CPU load. ④ I hoped to avoid this kind of deep-inspection :-/

Comment: I'd also try to see if runs without docker work better. If it is, you're left with much smaller parameter space to search in

Comment: Outside of the docker container I also observed *most* of the effects.  Left-over processes happen too rarely to be found in manual executions, but a smaller number of surefirebooter processes than expected is often.